# taskdef class weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Tags: java, web-services, ant, weblogic, jax-ws

i am develop a WebLogic web service but when try build WS with ant its exit with a error
[image]

My build.xml file:

```
<project default="all">
  <target name="all" depends="clean,build-service,deploy" />
  <target name="clean"> <delete dir="output" /> </target>
  <taskdef name="jwsc" classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask" />
  <target name="build-service">
    <jwsc srcdir="JAVAXWS" destdir="output/helloWorldEar">
      <jws file="src/main/com/SimpleImpl.java" type="JAXWS"/>
    </jwsc>
  </target>
  <target name="deploy">
    <!--add wldeploy task here -->
  </target>
</project>
```

After I created domain in web logic server I ran this `cmd` file
[image]

Above command didn't return nothing ( I'am not sure is OK or not).

Anyone face the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

When execute `setDomainEnv.cmd` domain script it create several environment variables only **For the current runtime session** so those environment variables are only available during this. After finish script execution `ant build-service` should work fine.